# How to touch/drag widgets under a CustomPaint in Flutter

Tags: flutter, drawing, touch-event, custom-painter

I have a media editor class which is editing photo/video with stickers/text/paint...

I want the user be able to draw above all others widgets like in this preview from SnapChat. This is what I'm trying to do :

[image]

So the `CustomPainter` is placed in last inside a `Stack`.

The problem is my `CustomPainter` which contain color draws is fitting the screen and is taking all touch events even when there is NO `GestureDetector` around it.

My code used for the painter is inspired by this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/painter) :

```
GestureDetector(
            onPanUpdate: (details) {
              _onPanUpdate(details);
            },
            onPanStart: (details) {
              _onPanStart(details);
            },
            onPanEnd: (details) {
              _onPanEnd(details);
            },
            child: CustomPaint(
              size: Size.infinite,
              willChange: true,
              painter: DrawPainter(painterController.pathHistory,
                  repaint: painterController),
            ),
          ),
```

As is said the `GestureDetector` is not the problem because if we remove it, the painter itself will receive all events only with this :

```
CustomPaint(
 size: Size.infinite
)
```

So the question is how can I display drawing color on top of screen and still touch & drag others widgets above in Stack like in the preview ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [touchable](https://pub.dev/packages/touchable). You can add gesture callbacks to individual shapes.